# How do I make an input/text field mandatory when the radio button assigned to it is checked?

Tags: javascript, forms

How do I make an input/text field mandatory(required) when the radio button assigned to it is checked/selected?

I need an input field to become mandatory once the corresponding radio button is selected:

**Radio Button A Text Field A 
 
Radio Button B Text Field B 
 
Radio Button C Text Field C**

So if Radio button A is selected, I need Text Field A to become mandatory. If Radio button B is selected, I need Text Field B to become mandatory and so on.

Answer (score 0):

First, to make things easy import jQuery into your HTML page, you can use the following tag which loads jQuery directly from Google's CDN:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Then, supposing you're going to use native HTML5 validation and that your form has a name of "form1", your radio button group is named "radio1" and your text input is named "text1", you can use the following Javascript code:

```
$(function(){
  var $form = $('form[name=form1]');
  $form.find('input[name=radio1]').click(function(){
    $form.find('input[name=text1]').attr('required', true);
  });
});
```

If you're doing validation "by hand" using an event binding on the form's submit event, then you can use instead a boolean control variable (e.g. named "requireInput" and `false` by default) to determine whether the input field is required or not, and set it to `true` inside the click event binding above.